# NetworkManager reaches outside but network service faiils

Tags: linux, networking, networkmanager

I am having IP `172.16.20.201` My proxy is on `172.16.15.8`  when using NetworkManager I can ping 172.16.15.8 with no issues.

Once I stop NetworkManager and start network service and do `service network restart`. I can no longer ping 172.16.15.8. neither can I ping 172.16.15.1. But I can ping 172.16.20.1

pings to 172.16.15.x says network unreachable.

But how does it work with NetworkManager ? and dont it work with network service ?

I am using Fedora 20.

-- EDIT --

with network service

```
$ route -en
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 em1
172.16.20.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 em1
```

with NetworkManager

```
$ route -en
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.20.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 em1
172.16.20.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U         0 0          0 em1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a network route or default route is missing since you can ping your local network and not outside it. But to give you a better response we'd need more responses.

To debug try comparing the output of the command "route -an" when you have NetworkManager running and when you don't have it. You should see differences there.

Comment: route -an says route: invalid option -- 'a'

Comment: added output of route -en

Comment: As you see from the output in the NetworkManager case you have the default gateway (0.0.0.0) with first case no. Therefore you have to set it. By hand can be done with "route add 172.16.20.1 default gw" otherwise a "gateway 172.16.20.1" in your interfaces file.